# Rails 4, attemt_login fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following a tutorial and beggienr in rails, in access_controller.rb
It gives me Error : Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/access/login"!

```
 def attempt_login

  if params[:username].present? && params[:password].present?
     found_user = AdminUser.where(:username => params[:username]).first
 if found_user
    authorized_user = found_user.authenticate(params[:password])
  end
 end
 if authorized_user
  # TODO: mark user as logged in
  flash[:notice] = "You are now logged in."
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')

else
  flash[:notice] = "Invalid username/password combination."
  redirect_to(:action => 'login')
end
 end
```

login.html.erb

```
 <% @page_title = "Admin Login" %>

  <div class="login">
 <%= form_tag access_path do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td><%= label_tag :username  %></td>
     <td><%= text_field_tag :username %></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag :password %></td>
  <td><%= password_field_tag :password %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><%= submit_tag("Log In") %></td>
</tr>
</table>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```

Here is my routes, which I think problem should be here but I don't know how to address it
 routes.rb

```
   get 'login', to: 'access#create'
  get 'access/login', to: 'access#create'

  resources :access do 
     member do
   get "login"
   post "login"
  get "logout"
   post "logout"
  get 'attempt_login'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explainatory, ***you don't have a route which matches [POST] "/access/login". In your routes.rb add this route:***

```
post "/access/login" => your_controller_name#your_method_name
```

Update:

***You are using `GET` verb for your route but your form is making a `POST` request and hence route not find error***. Change your route to this:

```
 get 'access/login', to: 'access#create', as: "access"
```

Change your routes to this:

```
  post 'access/login', to: 'access#create', as: "access"

  resources :access do 
    member do
      get "login"
      post "login"
      get "logout"
      post "logout"
      get 'attempt_login'
    end
  end
```

Also you in your create method you'll have to change

```
 redirect_to(:action => 'login')
```

to

```
 redirect_to access_path
```

Comment: Thanks, and that problem solved and now gives me another routing error, : No route matches {:action=>"login", :controller=>"access"}.

Comment: @Amir updated my answer. Also i don't see the purpose of using post member routes

Comment: @Mandeeo, I re change it to your code, and I  got  another error : ActionController::UrlGenerationError in AccessController#create
No route matches {:action=>"login", :controller=>"access"}

Comment: @Amir your routes are really messed up. Check update.

Comment: @Amir you'll also have to change your redirect url in create method. Check update